# Getting a 404 error when using jQuery to post to WordPress Ajax for a plugin

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a plugin that registers to handle an ajax call (and the registration call *is* run, I checked it with logging). When I use jQuery to post to it (via admin-ajax.php), it is never called and Wordpress throws a 404 error. But, if I instead type into the address bar of the browser `http://my-site.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=my_ajax_function` then it works!

**client side**

```
jQuery.post(
    {
        url: ajaxurl, //This is correct, I printed it out and it's "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"
        data: { action: 'my_ajax_function' },
        success: function(response)
        {
            //Never called
            console.dir( response );
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }
    //This is called
).fail( handleError );
```

**Server Side**

```
//This code IS called in my plugin's "load" hook
add_action( "wp_ajax_my_ajax_function", "handleAjax" );
add_action( "wp_ajax_nopriv_my_ajax_function", "handleAjax" );

//This is never called
public function handleAjax()
{
    echo "{ \"status\": \"ok\"}";
    die();
}
```

**EDIT: When I post a form to `ajaxurl` directly, it works! It's only through jQuery that it throws 404!** The below code executes perfectly:

```
//Posting without JQuery works!
form.method = "POST";
form.action = ajaxurl;
form.submit();
```

**EDIT #2: The error appears to be with JQuery!**

When I use Ajax directly (i.e. creating `XMLHttpRequest` in my code, calling `xmlHttpRequest.open(...)`, etc), it posts perfectly! Only JQuery throws the error!

How do I find out what in JQuery is causing this?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen no, that's how wordpress actions work. Notice the name "wp_ajax_my_ajax_function". That tells wordpress there's a "wp_ajax" handler named "my_ajax_function". Now notice the second part, "handleAjax". That tells wordpress that the handler "my_ajax_function" is represented by the function "handleAjax".

Answer (score 1):

you misunderstood [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [$.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), use this instead

```
jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type : 'post',
        data: { action: 'my_ajax_function' },
        success: function(response){
            console.dir( response );
        },
        dataType: "json"
}).fail( handleError );
```

$.post is a short hand of $.ajax for type *post*, which having following signature

```
jQuery.post( url [, data ] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) ] [, dataType ] )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$.post(ajaxurl,data,function(resp){
  console.log(resp);
},'json').fail(handleError);
```