# Getting 404 error when calling ajax in WordPress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I am developing a WordPress plugin and trying to use `wp_ajax` inside it.

This is my code:

```
function register_role_category_access() {
   wp_enqueue_script( 'role_category_access', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/category-restrict.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
   wp_localize_script( 'role_category_access', 'category_access_ajax_url', array(
      'url'   => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
      'nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'role_access_nonce' )
   ) );
}

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'register_role_category_access' ) );

function update_role_category_access() {
   $user_role = isset( $_POST[ 'user_role' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'user_role' ] : 'Not defined';
   $selected_cats = isset( $_POST[ 'selected_cats' ] ) ? $_POST[ 'selected_cats' ] : 'None selected';
   echo "Chosen role: " . $user_role . ' and categories are ' . $selected_cats;
   die();
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_category_access', array( $this,  'update_role_category_access' ) );
```

Since the above action could only be done from admin panel I am not using `wp_ajax_nopriv_*` hook.

JavaScript file content (`category-restrict.js`):

```
function updateAccess( obj ) {
    var selectedCatIds = "";
    var accessBox =  jQuery( obj ).closest( '.access-box' );
    var roleSlug = jQuery( accessBox ).find(".hidden_role").attr("value");
    var catList = jQuery( obj ).closest( '.access-box' ).find( '.category-list' );
    jQuery( catList ).children().each( function() {
        if( jQuery(this).is(":checked") ) {
        selectedCatIds += jQuery(this).val() + ",";
        }
    });

    var idLen = selectedCatIds.length;
    if( idLen > 0 ) {
        selectedCatIds = selectedCatIds.substring(0, idLen - 1);
    }

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: category_access_ajax_url, //wp_localize_script: 844
        data: {
            action: 'category_access', //wp_ajax_category_access: 71
            user_role: roleSlug,
            selected_cats: selectedCatIds,
        },
        success: function( result ) {
            alert( result );
        }
    });
}
```

But when I am calling the script I am getting the following error in console:

> `http://album.multibaselocal.com/wp-admin/[object%20Object]` 404 (Not
>   Found)

I looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23691823/getting-a-404-error-when-using-jquery-to-post-to-wordpress-ajax-for-a-plugin), but was not able to understand what wrong I have done since my knowledge in WordPress is still limited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `url` param in the AJAX call is wrong. `category_access_ajax_url` is a JS object that contains `url` and `nonce` so your code should be something like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: category_access_ajax_url.url, // access the url property inside category_access_ajax_url
    data: {
        action: 'category_access',
        user_role: roleSlug,
        selected_cats: selectedCatIds,
    },
    success: function( result ) {
        alert( result );
    }
});
```

I suggest renaming `category_access_ajax_url` to `category_access_ajax` to avoid confusion.

---

**Update:** You don't really need `category_access_ajax_url.url` because [WordPress defines a global variable called `ajaxurl` in the admin area](https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Administration_Side) that you can use for this purpose.

Comment: Ohhh!!! What a mistake. Thank you so much for your help. Works fine now :)